# Is there such a thing as a non-latching pulse switch?

Tags: switches, switching

Ideal would be mountable in a DB board on a DIN rail.

Something like a "single shot non-latching switch"

A normal button like a push button remains closed for as long as I hold my finger on it. What I'm looking for is a switch that requires me to remove my finger and press again if I want another brief connection (pulse).

I want to use it as a trigger.

Alternatively, there must be safety applications where things should not just restart when the power comes back on after a power failure.

If the power fails, then manual intervention is required to restore the power, and that can't be overridden by physically keeping the switch in the on position.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Might this help?  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/416929/latching-switch-momentary-pulse-output-when-switching-on

Comment: What's a DB board? Try looking for a monostable.

Comment: Distribution board

Comment: distribution board board?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many pulse relays available for industrial control systems. These will come in standard industrial control voltages, 24 VDC, 110 VAC and 230 VAC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTh9VZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A simple pulse circuit.*

When SW1 is pressed OUT will turn on until RLY1 is energised (which will be very quickly). This may or may not be adequate for your application.

The industrial devices mentioned above will have adjustable pulse times.

Comment: And if someone wants to hack the system, and glue SW1 down, with some tape...? This is what I'm trying to prevent

Comment: Work it out! RLY1 will remain energised and OUT will be disconnected (switched off).

Comment: You can also make one out of electronics but I guess that might not be suitable for a distribution board kind of application

Comment: Might be with pointing out that the industrial device would (or could) be a simple delay timer if wired this way.